# opengl failing to draw mesh

Tags: c, opengl, mesh

SOLVED: I'm not really sure how though... thanks for all your help guys.

I tried `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);` but the mesh is still not visible.

Basically I'm trying to draw a mesh (made from verts, normals, and texture coords) in OpenGL, using a display list. The mesh is on .obj format (exported from 3ds max 2013)

The problem is that the mesh is not visible.

To draw the display list I'm just using `glCallLists (list, 1);`

I have verified that I can draw things to the screen by drawing a point in the center of the screen and that works fine.

Could it be possible that the camera is positioned inside the mesh? If so is there an OpenGL state that I could enable to allow me to see the inside of a set of verts?

I know that the data I have is all valid, verified by printing each vert, normal and texture coord to a file before adding it to the display list, it looks valid.

I have dont no `glTranslatef` or anything like that, my projection matrix is setup like this:

```
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();
gluPerspective (45.0, (float)1024/(float)768, -9999, 9999);
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity ();
```

If you want to have a look at the .obj file, here it is: http://pastebin.com/PpG3vG5e

This is how I create the display list:

```
list = glGenLists (1);
glNewList (list, GL_COMPILE);
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);

for (i = 0; i < data.face_count; i++)
{
    // first vert
    normal[0][0] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[0]]->e[0];
    normal[0][1] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[0]]->e[1];
    normal[0][2] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[0]]->e[2];
    tex[0][0] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[0]]->e[0];
    tex[0][1] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[0]]->e[1];
    tex[0][2] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[0]]->e[2];
    vert[0][0] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[0]]->e[0];
    vert[0][1] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[0]]->e[1];
    vert[0][2] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[0]]->e[2];

    // second vert
    normal[1][0] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[1]]->e[0];
    normal[1][1] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[1]]->e[1];
    normal[1][2] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[1]]->e[2];
    tex[1][0] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[1]]->e[0];
    tex[1][1] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[1]]->e[1];
    tex[1][2] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[1]]->e[2];
    vert[1][0] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[1]]->e[0];
    vert[1][1] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[1]]->e[1];
    vert[1][2] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[1]]->e[2];

    // third vert
    normal[2][0] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[2]]->e[0];
    normal[2][1] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[2]]->e[1];
    normal[2][2] = (float)data.vertex_normal_list[data.face_list[i]->normal_index[2]]->e[2];
    tex[2][0] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[2]]->e[0];
    tex[2][1] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[2]]->e[1];
    tex[2][2] = (float)data.vertex_texture_list[data.face_list[i]->texture_index[2]]->e[2];
    vert[2][0] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[2]]->e[0];
    vert[2][1] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[2]]->e[1];
    vert[2][2] = (float)data.vertex_list[data.face_list[i]->vertex_index[2]]->e[2];

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        glNormal3f (normal[j][0], normal[j][1], normal[j][2]);
        glTexCoord3f (tex[j][0], tex[j][1], tex[j][2]);
        glVertex3f (vert[j][0], vert[j][1], vert[j][2]);
    }
}

glEnd ();
glEndList ();
```

EDIT:
I've tried things like:

```
glTranslatef (0, 0, 5);
glCallList (mesh);
glTranslatef (0, 0, 0);
```

but they don't work either :(

EDIT:

@datenwolf
Here is the code I use to draw it:

```
Draw_Begin ();
Mdl_Draw (list, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Draw_End ();
```

Comment: A few things are possible: your mesh could be really small, your mesh could be completely inside of the clipping plane, or your display function is missing a `glFlush()`.

Comment: I don't think the mesh is really small since it has verticies like (31.6352 139.3443 145.9452). (I am doing no scaling either). Do I need a glFlush? I thought glCallLists then SwapBuffers would be sufficient. (EDIT: I added glFlush after glCallLists but still no mesh)

Comment: If you are using double buffering, then you want to swap the buffers. See datenwolf's answer. He is right.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
gluPerspective (45.0, (float)1024/(float)768, -9999, 9999);
```

is wrong. In a perspective projection both the near and the far plane distance must be of the same sign, i.e. both positive or both negative. Also the absolute value of the near plane must be smaller than the absolute value of the far plane. *And the near plane distance must be nonzero*. In mathematical notation:

*sgn(near) = sgn(far) ^ 0 < |near| < |far|*

Usually both near and far are chosen positive. Also as a rule of thumb the near clipping plane should be chosen as fer away as possible. The far plane can be placed at infinity (exploting some of the properties of homogenous matrices), but usually is placed as close as possible to max out depth buffer resolution.

Comment: I changed it to be `gluPerspective (45.0, (float)1024/(float)768, 0, 9999);` but still no change

Comment: @TomTetlaw `0` doesn't work either. Just use a value as large as possible, but small enough for your objects not to get clipped away in any reasonable viewing position (really depends on your scene), but definitely not `0`.

Comment: @TomTetlaw: Choose the near plane as far away as possible. Your model will be placed around the origin, so you'll have to move it anyway. How about you try to set the near and far plane to 5 and 10 and move the model to Z = -7.5 ?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll remember that next time. I changed it to 0.1 but still no mesh :(

Comment: @TomTetlaw: Sorry, but what is so hard about to understand the statement "choose the near plance distance as large as possible."? 0.1 is not large, it's small. How about using 5 or 10 as a near plane distance? And use glTranslate on the modelview matrix to move the model into sight?

Comment: @datenwolf I tried both 5 and 10. I also tried `glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);` to move it forwards into the screen, then used `gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0, 1, 0);` to attempt to see the mesh but it still wasn't there. I would have expected to be able to see the mesh from the inside without having to use `glTranslatef` and `gluLookAt` ? Maybe it's a problem with the display list... I will look further

Comment: @TomTetlaw: It would help to post the full source code of what you have done so far to pastebin.com or similar.

Comment: Okay, here's the relevant code:
opengl code: http://pastebin.com/n9wJVeJr
model code: http://pastebin.com/fVhEuren

Comment: @TomTetlaw: Well, I can tell you, why you don't see your model drawn: Because nowhere in your code you're actually making any draw calls. Also you shouldn't load the identity matrix in the model drawing function, as you normally want to be able to stack upon the existing matrix.